# Ruby on Rails value is being saved correctly, but changing when I access the record

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm running a script to change the value of an attribute of my object.  It is being saved as the correct value, but when I access the record the value is different than what was saved.

```
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE `eligibility_data` SET `adjusted_foo` = 2633, `bar_calc` = 1250675.0, `updated_at` = '2015-07-10 16:13:39.904760' WHERE `eligibility_data`.`id` = 2590
(0.3ms)  COMMIT

<EligibilityData id: 2590, bar_calc: 1250680.0>
```

There is no where in my logs where the value is changed before I access it.  Does anyone know why this would be happening?

Comment: The model seems different. `school_eligibility_date` table is usually refered to as `SchoolEligibiityData` model.

Comment: If it was altered that alteration was probably logged. Are you sure this is the only alteration? Are you sure that you're retrieving the current data? What does `EligibilityData.find(2590)` yield?

Comment: I'm doing it directly into mysql and it's still altering the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my float to a decimal and it solved the problem.
example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba8f7/1